# Change ul background when li is in hover or active state

Tags: jquery, css, background

I have a list, and I need to change the background image of the UL when hovering over each child. I've done that using [the code here](http://jsbin.com/donebaheqano/1/) (here I'm using color instead of background image).

Now, if I click on item 1 there's an 'active' class dynamically added to it as I'm taken to .page-1. Here I need the background to show the corresponding image (or yellow color, per the example). I tried CSS:

```
.page-1 #menu {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

But the color disappears as soon as I hover over the other items. I think I should use the `.hasClass` method, but I'm not good with jQuery so I can't completely figure it out.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: i want to know if you click on item1 it takes you to different page or the same...

Comment: It's a different page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use style and class attribute at the same time. The style attribute will override color of class attribute.

```
<ul id="menu" style="background-color:yellow" class="pink">
```

On hover event you just add class to #menu, on click event you just change style of #menu.

```
$('.item_1').hover(function() {
    $('#menu').addClass('yellow');
}, function() {
    $('#menu').removeClass('yellow');
});

$('.item_1').click(function() {
    $('#menu').css('background-color', 'yellow');
    return false;
});
```

Here is example [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/manassornpn/a9p2rvmd/)

Comment: Thanks! I used part of your code and some CSS and got what I needed :)

Answer (score 0):

Now i think i have a solution for your problem...

create three different **html** files for item-1, item-2 and item-3
if you click on item 1....then change the inline style for `ul` in item-1 file to...

```
<ul id="menu" style="background-color:yellow">

</ul>
```

if you want to do it with jquery

take three classes

```
.item1background{
    background-color:yellow;  
 }
.item2background{
    background-color:gray;  
 }
.item1background{
    background-color:pink;  
 }
```

Now whenever somebody click on an item then we dynamically added one of the above class.

```
$("#menu .item_1").click(function(){
    $("#menu").addClass("item1background");
});
```

same you can do for rest of iem's

you can learn more about `addClass()` method @ http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_css_classes.asp

Comment: Can't change the HTML, that's why I'm resorting to jQuery :(

Comment: @brunn check it out this will help you

Comment: When I click on an item, I see the class briefly flashing on the UL, but as soon as the page finishes loading it disappears.

Comment: @brunn remove the inline css for #menu which is background-color:white; it overrides the change...

Comment: I can't remove it because I'm actually using background images; I used colors on my example only to make it easier... But I got it working now. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

In your comment you said that **it will go to another page**, then I believe you cannot get what you want just by changing the CSS `background-color` of your `#menu` using jQuery. Every manipulation that you did using `jQuery` will be removed when you refresh/reload your page, because your page simply reset everything back to its default state..

The only solution that I can come up with is to use [HTML5 LocalStorage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) to save your `ul` colour, like below:

```
// Store
localStorage.setItem("lastname", "Smith");
// Retrieve
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("lastname");
```

By doing so, everytime you reload your page you need to check your localStorage for the latest colour for your `ul`.